# Capture all data posted by client to server

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing an application in C# using HttpClient. My code is flowing through a lot of functions and then finally it does a PostAsyc.

What I want to do is that I want to have a EventHandler which is called when PostAsyc is done. and in that event handler I want to capture and print everything which the client has sent to the server .

Is this possible in .NET HTTPClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a message handler class like this,

```
public class LoggingMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            // Log whatever you want here
            Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

and then create your HttpClient with the message handler as part of the request/response pipeline

```
var client = new HttpClient(new LoggingMessageHandler() {InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler()});
client.PostAsync(...) // Whatever
```

Any request you make from this point on will pass through the LoggingRequestHandler.

By taking this approach you do not need to wrap the HttpClient object and it is also easy to retrofit into existing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void PostData(string data, Action<string> callback)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.PostAsync("uri", new StringContent(data));

    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((trep) =>
        {
            string response = trep.Result;
            callback(response);
        });
    });
}
```

Instead of using `Action<string> callback` you can define an event delegate and use that also, this gives you more flexibility of attaching multiple receivers.

```
public class PostEventArgs : EventArgs { public string Data { get; set; } }
public event EventHandler<PostEventArgs> postDone;

public void PostData(string data)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.PostAsync("uri", new StringContent(data));

    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((trep) =>
        {
            string response = trep.Result;
            if (postDone != null)
                postDone(this, new PostEventArgs() { Data = response });
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

First Case

```
serviceObj.PostData("some data", (response)=> { Console.WriteLine(response); });
```

Second case

```
serviceObj.postDone += (obj,response)=>{ Console.WriteLine(response); }; // register only once
serviceObj.PostData("some data");
```

Updated with `Task.ContinueWith`.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Result`. Either `await` or use `ContinueWith()` instead.